# Export Hair particle system to ThreeJS

Tags: particles, hair, three.js, webgl

I am having trouble exporting a feather made with a hair particle system to ThreeJS. I have followed a lot of tutorials and looked all over but none of the methods I have found have been successful in the export. Does anyone have any guidance on doing so?

Comment: Any particle system will need to be converted to mesh(es) before exporting, I don't think it can export as a particle system.

Comment: yeah I went through a few different processes of doing this and had no luck of it showing in threejs